# delimitar parallax con javascript

Tags: javascript, parallax

tengo este scroll https://codepen.io/StephenScaff/pen/WxoVBo que funciona perfecto cuando lo uso al final de una página pero cuando lo colóco en otra posición el texto final "monta" a la sección siguiente, ejemplo de la sobreposición (el último texto): http://dev.jazm.in/ox/s/

Estuve revisando el archivo js y me parece que se debe añadir algo más, no manejo mucho js por lo que me atrevo a consultar por este medio.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te está ocurriendo porque el `section` siguiente al paralax (donde no quieres que se te monte el texto), no tiene asignado ningún `position`, y además no tiene asignado ningún `z-index`, por lo que todo lo que haya en el resto de los `section` (que tienen `z-index: 5`), quedará por encima.

Una solución sería darle al `section`, en el que no quieres que se te monte el texto, las siguientes reglas CSS:

**CSS**

```
position: relative;
z-index: 6;
```

Con eso deberías de tener solucionado el problemilla que te ha surgido.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por su tiempo, me ayudó bastante.